# Plotting model in Keras

Tags: plot, keras, model

I'm trying to plot my model in Keras, like this:

```
# Plot model graph
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file='Model1.png')
from IPython.display import Image
Image(retina=True, filename='Model1.png')
```

Which I get the following result: [my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLbkK.png)

But, I've seen somewhere in the internet, that someone plotted his model, like this: [model I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzcUq.png)

How can I change my code to plot like that? With the input/output information of each layer of my model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the parameter `show_shapes=True`.

from the `tf.keras` documentation:

> show_shapes: whether to display shape information.

(have a closer look here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/plot_model )